# Submitting a http post via python and seeing escape characters in the json posted

Tags: python, httprequest, python-requests

I am posting via python (totally new language for me so I am sure I am overlooking something basic) and seeing escape characters in the json posted to the server which obviously results in invalid json.  Here is my code:

```
import requests
#try three different ways to escape json - all result in the backslash being submitted to the server in the post
json = """{"testId": "616fdb5e-40c1-326a-81a4-433051627e6d","testName": "nameHere"}"""    
#json = '{"testId": "616fdb5e-40c1-326a-81a4-433051627e6d","testName": "nameHere"}'   
#json = "{\"testId\": \"616fdb5e-40c1-326a-81a4-433051627e6d\",\"testName\": \"nameHere\"}"
response = requests.post("http://localhost:8888", data=None, json=json)
```

I am posting locally to fiddler and see that the escape characters are still there.  Here is what is posted:

```
"{\"testId\": \"616fdb5e-40c1-326a-81a4-433051627e6d\",\"testName\": \"nameHere\"}"
```

I would expect the library to strip out escape characters.  Is that not the case?

The other weird thing is that the characters aren't there when I am running the code, at least from what I can tell:

```
json
'{"testId": "616fdb5e-40c1-326a-81a4-433051627e6d","testName": "nameHere"}'
json.find("\\")
-1
```

Comment: Why are you putting quotes around the brackets. The json library will turn a python dict into a json string. Don't build the string yourself.

Comment: hah, thx. Knew it was something simple. Try another language and look like and idiot.  If you want to post that as the answer I will accept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is don't submit a string, the response method wants a dict.  Code that works:

```
import requests
json_dict = {"testId": "616fdb5e-40c1-326a-81a4-433051627e6d","testName": "nameHere"}
response = requests.post("http://localhost:8888", data=None, json=json_dict)
```